# what is the method used for getting all the elements(substrings) in iterable.. as we get first substring with iterable.iterator().next();

Tags: guava, splitter

This is my code:

```
a1 = Splitter.fixedLength(4).split("goodgirl");
System.out.println("a1=" + a1);
a3[1] = a1.iterator().next();
System.out.println("a3[1]=" + a3[1]);
```

When I use Splitter class from Guava library, my string i.e. "goodgirl" gets split into [good, girl] as fixed length is 4 and gets stored in a1.

Now with `a3[1] = a1.iterator().next();` I can get the substring "good" from a1.

How can i get the next substring (i.e. "girl")?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Or use Iterables.get(Iterator, 1);

```
Iterator<String> iterator = Splitter.fixedLength(4).split("goodgirl").iterator();
            while(iterator.hasNext()){
                System.out.println(iterator.next());
            }
```

next() return the next token, you should use it with **hasNext**

Comment: hasNext() Returns true if the iteration has more elements. But i need a method that returns second element. As i can get first element with iterable.iterator().next();

Comment: @mkr since you have guava: Iterables.get(iterator, 1);

Comment: And one more thing, has.next() is leading me to infinite loop, to stop it i need to use endOfData(). Can you help me? (Means the syntax.) @Eugene